# Migration java8 and WLS 12c to Java11 and WLS 14c

Tags: jaxb, weblogic, jax-ws, java-11, moxy

I have a java application that serves Soap xml web services, in the present case it is java8 app and running on weblogic 12c. I decided to upgrade it java11 and also weblogic 14c. As far as I read from Oracle's documentations Oracle removed **jaxws** and **jaxb** from JDK11 permanently.Based on a few articles I've read, all I have to do in **pom.xml** before migration;

- Set java version => **11**
- Set maven-compiler-plugin version min => **3.8.0**
- Put **jaxws** and **jaxb** dependencies explicitly

I have done those things and I have added dependencies like

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-jxc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have removed old **jaxb** implementation and added **MOXY** implementation. Every thing is fine until deployment to the **wls 14c**, a successfully compilation, I can see the jars in my war file;

- **jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar**
- **jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar**
- **jaxws-rt-2.3.1.jar**
- **eclipselink-2.7.6.jar**

When I try to deploy war file to wls 14c, I get weird stack trace error on wsl 14c console logs;

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/sun/xml/ws/db/glassfish/JAXBRIContextFactory.getContext(Ljavax/xml/bind/Marshaller;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/spi/db/BindingContext; @8: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @8
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/sun/xml/ws/db/glassfish/JAXBRIContextFactory', 'javax/xml/bind/Marshaller' }
    stack: { 'com/sun/xml/ws/db/glassfish/JAXBRIContextFactory', 'com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b c000 34b6 0035 b600 36b0          

    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I couldn't understand the error message, what am I missing ? Could you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, if you are running your app on wls14c, the only thing you have to do is adddin **JAX-RT** dependency with **provided** scope. Because in java11, jax-ws and jaxb are removed but not in wls14c.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This is covered in https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/wlupg/compat.html#GUID-575BFB76-FA68-44C8-A628-65616CB4A1EF which says: 

The following Java EE classes that were in the Java SE runtime have been removed in Java SE 11: JAXB, JAX-WS/JWS/SOAP, JTA, Activation Framework, JSR 250 common annotation, CORBA.

New jar files have been added to the classpath to account for this.